# Utilize 100% discount voucher in Stripe account

Tags: php, stripe-payments

If we are using 100% discount voucher code and price gets 0 and needs to be processed via Stripe how can we do it? Or via subscriptions that are free how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The minimum value for a charge is $0.50 USD.  If the invoice has an amount smaller than this, it will not create a charge, but rather add that as a "debt" on the customer for the next invoice.

Answer (score 0):

> `amount` A positive integer in the smallest currency unit (e.g., 100 cents to charge $1.00 or 100 to charge ¥100, a zero-decimal currency) representing how much to charge. The minimum amount is $0.50 US or equivalent in charge currency.

From [Stripe API Reference](https://stripe.com/docs/api#charge_object-amount).